# Can't create my table

Tags: php, mysql, create-table

I already tried with/without the quotes, with/without the `or exit()`, I tripple checked I am connected to the DB correctly.

**Edit:** Now I am getting my own custom error:

```
$username="user";
$password="*****";
$hostname="localhost";

mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or exit("Error: @mysql_connect.");
mysql_select_db("test") or exit("Error: @mysql_select_db.");

mysql_query("CREATE TABLE propiedades(
'id' SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'colonia' VARCHAR(35),
'zona' VARCHAR(35),
'precio' DECIMAL(9,2),
'usd' BOOLEAN,
'tipo' TINYINT,
'venta' BOOLEAN,
'recamaras' TINYINT,
'banos' TINYINT,
'mbanos' TINYINT,
'plantas' TINYINT,
'construccion' SMALLINT,
'terreno' SMALLINT,
'edad' TINYINT,
'uploaded' TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
'updated' TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
'ocultar' BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY (id))") or exit("Error: @mysql_query CREATE TABLE.");
```

My code is throwing `"Error: @mysql_query CREATE TABLE."`

Comment: That is a PHP error, it's not a SQL parse error. Can you include the surrounding PHP code in your post?

Comment: Is that all of your code? If not can you show the rest. The error you're getting is a PHP syntax error so it's likely to do with how you've constructed that statement in your code.

Comment: Pasting raw SQL into PHP code context won't work. You need to utilize a database API.

Comment: What Marty said, also can you type the complete php code instead of just the query? Show us how you feed the query to mysql through php.

Comment: You need to include the code segement exactly as it is in your file, in that order. It appears as you may just have put raw SQL while in a PHP context, as @mario said.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't check for your query's syntax, I'm just demonstrating how it should be done. As mario in a comment above said, you can't feed pure mysql code into php and expect it to work... to do so you need to use mysql api or pdo.

```
$sql = '
    CREATE TABLE propiedades(
    `id` SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `colonia` VARCHAR(35),
    `zona` VARCHAR(35),
    `precio` DECIMAL(9,2),
    `usd` BOOLEAN,
    `tipo` TINYINT,
    `venta` BOOLEAN,
    `recamaras` TINYINT,
    `banos` TINYINT,
    `mbanos` TINYINT,
    `plantas` TINYINT,
    `construccion` SMALLINT,
    `terreno` SMALLINT,
    `edad` TINYINT,
    `uploaded` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `updated` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `ocultar` BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (id))';

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result)
    exit("Error: @CREATE TABLE.");
```

Comment: success! I changed my `'` into `\``

Comment: Just to give you some more info, putting column names in `` in mysql statements helps mysql not confuse reserved keywords with column names. which means you could have a column named select and actually be able to select it by putting it within ``... e.g `SELECT \`select\` FROM selections`

Answer (score -1):

Well, you should probably put your whole SQL code into **mysql_query** function

as an argument:

```
$result = mysql_query('CREATE TABLE propiedades(
    "id" SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    "colonia" VARCHAR(35),
    "zona" VARCHAR(35),
    "precio" DECIMAL(9,2),
    "usd" BOOLEAN,
    "tipo" TINYINT,
    "venta" BOOLEAN,
    "recamaras" TINYINT,
    "banos" TINYINT,
    "mbanos" TINYINT,
    "plantas" TINYINT,
    "construccion" SMALLINT,
    "terreno" SMALLINT,
    "edad" TINYINT,
    "uploaded" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "updated" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "ocultar" BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (id))');
```

Comment: okey no longer syntax error, but I get my own error `mysql_query("CREATE TABLE propiedades('id' SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ... 'ocultar' BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,PRIMARY KEY (id))") or exit("Error: @mysql_query CREATE TABLE.");`

Comment: What that error says? And try: `exit("Error: ".mysql_error())` instead of your code - it will output error message if something go wrong.